# PHP - Downloading very large files with fsockopen(), fgets() and feof()

Tags: php

I have a simple download function in a class that might be dealing with files of many hundreds of megabytes at a time from an Amazon Web Services bucket. The whole file cannot be loaded into memory at once, so it must be streamed directly to a file pointer. This is my understanding as this is the first time I've dealt with this issue and I'm picking things up as I go along.

I've ended up with this, based on a 4 KB file buffer which simple testing showed was a good size:

```
        $fs = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

        if (!$fs) {
          $this->writeDebugInfo("FAILED ", $errstr . '(' . $errno . ')');
        } else {
          $out = "GET $file HTTP/1.1\r\n";
          $out .= "Host: $host\r\n";
          $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
          fwrite($fs, $out);

          $fm = fopen ($temp_file_name, "w");
          stream_set_timeout($fs, 30);

          while(!feof($fs) && ($debug = fgets($fs)) != "\r\n" ); // ignore headers

          while(!feof($fs)) {
            $contents = fgets($fs, 4096); 
            fwrite($fm, $contents);
            $info = stream_get_meta_data($fs);
            if ($info['timed_out']) {
              break;
            }
          }
          fclose($fm);
          fclose($fs);

          if ($info['timed_out']) {
            // Delete temp file if fails
            unlink($temp_file_name);
            $this->writeDebugInfo("FAILED - Connection timed out: ", $temp_file_name);
          } else {
            // Move temp file if succeeds
            $media_file_name = str_replace('temp/', 'media/', $temp_file_name);
            rename($temp_file_name, $media_file_name);
            $this->writeDebugInfo("SUCCESS: ", $media_file_name);
          }
        }
```

In testing it's fine. However I have got into a conversation with someone who is saying that I am not understanding how `fgets()` and `feof()` work together, and he's mentioning chunked encoding as a more efficient method.

Is the code generally OK, or am I missing something vital here? What is the benefit that chunked encoding will give me?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems fine to me, however I have a few comments.

1) Don't create a HTTP packet yourself, i.e. don't send the HTTP request. Instead use something like CURL. This is more fool proof and will support a wider range of responses the server might reply with. Additionally CURL can be setup to write directly to a file, saving you doing it yourself.

2) Using fgets may be a problem if you are reading binary data. Fgets reads to the end of a line, and with binary data this may corrupt your download. Instead I suggest fread($fs, 4096); which will handle both text and binary data.

2) Chunked encoding is a way for a webserver to send you the response in multiple chunks. I don't think this is very useful to you, however, a better encoding that the webserver might support is the gzip encoding. This would allow the webserver to compress the response on the fly. If you use a library like CURL, it will tell the server it supports gzip, and then automatically decompress it for you.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

1) I did use CURL and CURLOPT_FILE but I couldn't see how data timeout would work from a dropped connection mid-transfer. I considered set_time_limit in the main while() loop and catching exceptions, but went back to fsockopen instead.

2) I am retrieving binary data (compressed media) and occasionally get errors. fread() looks like a straight replacement.

3) Any addiitonal compression will help, so I'll look at this. I've read mroe on chunked encoding and still can't see the immediate benefit though.

Many thanks for the reply.

Comment: Time outs in CURL should be easy. I would recommend going back to CURL and if you have a problem with the timeouts ask another more specific question.

Also, I think you misread what I wrote. You do NOT need Chunked encoding. Gzip encoding (which is different) should compress the output if the server supports it. Anyway, CURL would take care of all of this.

Comment: I'll review CURL wrt timeouts. I understood about not needing chunked encoding, but had just read a little around the subject to increase my awareness of it. I'll be happy to do without it.

Comment: It looks like CURL timeouts would need to be checked using a CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION callback. This CURLOPT is only available in PHP 5.3+ which I'm not using. So maybe in the next minor release. I'm very surprised not to find a CURLOPT_DATATIMEOUT or similar. Maybe I just can't see for looking.

Answer (score 1):

Don't deal with sockets, optimize your code and use the [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) library, [PHP cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php). Like this:

```
$url = 'http://'.$host.'/'.$file;
// create a new cURL resource
$fh = fopen ($temp_file_name, "w");
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Pretty much what I used in my previous attempt with CURL, though I had set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER which I can see now is not required (I think I can see why anyway...). Also played with a PHP bug for an hour before finding this: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49517

Comment: in fact setting the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER will give you a memory error if the file its big, cause when you set the return is saved in memory instead to write it into a file. I use this method to migrate websites from a test hosting to production. its pretty fast, although some hosts disable the executing tar or connect to other servers with firewalls.

Comment: I understand it's more used for '$data = curl_exec($ch)' when CURLOPT_FILE isn't used. The memory error is a good one to know and avoid - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And the final result in case it helps anyone else. I also wrapped the whole thing in a retry loop to decrease the risk of a completely failed download, but it does increase the use of resources:

```
      do {
        $fs = fopen('http://' . $host . $file, "rb");

        if (!$fs) {
          $this->writeDebugInfo("FAILED ", $errstr . '(' . $errno . ')');
        } else {
          $fm = fopen ($temp_file_name, "w");
          stream_set_timeout($fs, 30);

          while(!feof($fs)) {
            $contents = fread($fs, 4096); // Buffered download
            fwrite($fm, $contents);
            $info = stream_get_meta_data($fs);
            if ($info['timed_out']) {
              break;
            }
          }
          fclose($fm);
          fclose($fs);

          if ($info['timed_out']) {
            // Delete temp file if fails
            unlink($temp_file_name);
            $this->writeDebugInfo("FAILED on attempt " . $download_attempt . " - Connection timed out: ", $temp_file_name);
            $download_attempt++;
            if ($download_attempt < 5) {
              $this->writeDebugInfo("RETRYING: ", $temp_file_name);
            }
          } else {
            // Move temp file if succeeds
            $media_file_name = str_replace('temp/', 'media/', $temp_file_name);
            rename($temp_file_name, $media_file_name);
            $this->newDownload = true;
            $this->writeDebugInfo("SUCCESS: ", $media_file_name);
          }
        }
      } while ($download_attempt < 5 && $info['timed_out']);
```